# How to log Python warnings in a Django log file?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application that I am migrating from v1.8 to v1.10. In the process of doing this work, I ran my application via:

`python -Wall manage.py runserver`

Doing so causes a number of Python warnings to appear in my console. I'd like to have these warnings show up in my Django application log, so I can examine them later. I thought my application's log handler would catch these warnings, but it doesn't. The log handler looks like the following (as taken from settings.py):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myapp.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
    }
}
```

How can I capture Python warnings (with `-Wall`) in my Django log for examination later?

Comment: Pipe them to file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warnings shown in `python -Wall manage.py <command>` are generated using warnings module. In Python2.7 logging module documentation, they have a section showing how to [integrate messages from warnings module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#integration-with-the-warnings-module) to logging.

Add these to your settings file.

```
import logging
logging.captureWarnings(True)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myapp.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

After adding it, try to run any `manage.py` command and you can see the warnings written to your `myapp.log` file.

This line instructs logging to capture the py.warnings *warnings*:

```
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

This instructs logging to route (in this example to the *file* handler) warnings from the py.warnings logger:

```
    'py.warnings': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': True
    }
```