# Logging warnings in Django: filter not returning anything

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to setup Django logging to log deprecation warnings. I normally wouldn't have a formatter like this or output it to console, that is just to test and show it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
def is_deprecated(record):
    if record.exc_info:
        exc_type, exc_value = record.exc_info[:2]
        print(exc_value)
        if isinstance(exc_value, DeprecationWarning) or isinstance(exc_value, PendingDeprecationWarning):
            return True
    return False

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'stuff': {
            'format': 'This works!'
        }
    },
    'filters': {
      'is_deprecated': {
          '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
          'callback': is_deprecated,
      },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'filters': ['is_deprecated'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'stuff',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

It should output "This works!" when it hits a deprecation warning however it won't. I am running python with these alerts on

> python -Wd

So I can see the regular Django alert but I can't get the logger to detect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the you use the `-Wd` argument it displays the warning but is not treated as an exception (Django log only handles exceptions) you can change this behavior using `warnings.simplefilter('error')` in some initial part (like the settings.py, **init**.py, manage.py, etc.) or use the `python -W error` command

reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter

Comment: On top of this, simplefilter will raise the equivalent exception. If you do not want this you can follow this solution to handle the warnings with Django's logging silently

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752766/how-to-log-python-warnings-in-a-django-log-file